Parse from json float or string into float
I need to parse json into a struct in golang and the final value is a float64
But it seems that some inputs encode it as a string and some encode it as a float64
This is across a lot of variables so I would rather not make a custom function for each field
What is the best way to do this in golang?
I know the json tags can let values be stored as strings,  but now that I am receiving raw floats it is starting to error out
This is a parsing FROM json only operation,  so I do not care about what it implies or makes impossible for encoding TO json
Example code:
type Example struct {
  var1  float64 `json:"var1"`
}

func main() {
  var ex Example
  json.Unmarshal([]byte("{\"var1\":10.0}", &ex)
  json.Unmarshal([]byte("{\"var1\":\"10.0\"}", &ex)
}


Create a type that unmarshals a JSON string or JSON number to a float64.
type floatOrString float64

func (f *floatOrString) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {

    // Step 1: Get a string containing the float literal.

    var s string
    if len(b) > 0 && b[0] == '"' {
        // It's a JSON string. To remove the quotes and
        // to handle any escaped characters, unmarshal to
        // a Go string.
        if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &s); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    } else {
        // Assume that it's a JSON number.  If the assumption
        // is incorrect, then the call to ParseFloat below will 
        // return an error.
        s = string(b)
    }

    // Step 2: Convert string to float.

    pf, err := strconv.ParseFloat(s, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *f = floatOrString(pf)
    return nil
}

Use it like this:
type Example struct {
    Var1 floatOrString `json:"var1"`
}

var ex Example
json.Unmarshal([]byte("{\"var1\":123.0}"), &ex)
fmt.Println(ex)
json.Unmarshal([]byte("{\"var1\":\"456.0\"}"), &ex)
fmt.Println(ex)

https://go.dev/play/p/-ubMyX93Tdj
